# Category items won't display on a single row

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am finishing up a custom Storefront child theme for a client. Yesterday, when I began work, I noticed the homepage category row items were displaying on two rows. I had made no changes to any of the template code or CSS. No matter what I do, I cannot get them to display on a single row. I have removed the float, put float:left back, removed the margins and padding, without any of the changes correcting the way that the category items display.

site url: https://test.onyour6designs.com

**CSS**

```
.page-template-template-homepage-php .site-main .columns-3 ul.products, 
.storefront-full-width-content .site-main .columns-3 ul.products {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.page-template-template-homepage-php .site-main .columns-3 ul.products li.product, 
.storefront-full-width-content .site-main .columns-3 ul.products li.product {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 29%;
    margin-right: 0;
}
.page-template-template-homepage-php .site-main .columns-3 ul.products li.product:last-child, 
.storefront-full-width-content .site-main .columns-3 ul.products li.product:last-child {
      margin-right: 0;
}

Other CSS:
storefront style.css
ol, ul {
    margin: 0 0 1.618em 3em;
    padding: 0;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

woocommerce.css
ul.products {
    margin-left: 0;
    clear: both;
}
ul.products:after, ul.products:before {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
ul.products:after {
    clear: both;
}
ul.products:after, ul.products:before {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
```

**Custom PHP (in child theme)**

storefront-template-functions.php

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'storefront_oy6d_product_categories' ) ) {
/**
 * Display Product Categories
 * Hooked into the `homepage` action in the homepage template
 *
 * @since  1.0.0
 * @param array $args the product section args.
 * @return void
 */
function storefront_oy6d_product_categories( $args ) {

    if ( is_woocommerce_activated() ) {

        $args = apply_filters( 'storefront_oy6d_product_categories_args', array(
            'limit'             => 3,
            'columns'           => 3,
            'child_categories'  => 0,
            'orderby'           => 'name',
            'title'             => __( 'Shop by Category', 'storefront' ),
        ) );

        echo '<section class="storefront-oy6d-product-categories phone">';

        do_action( 'storefront_homepage_before_product_categories' );

        echo '<h2 class="section-title">' . wp_kses_post( $args['title'] ) . '</h2>';

        do_action( 'storefront_homepage_after_product_categories_title' );

        echo storefront_do_shortcode( 'product_categories', array(
            'number'  => intval( $args['limit'] ),
            'columns' => intval( $args['columns'] ),
            'orderby' => esc_attr( $args['orderby'] ),
            'parent'  => esc_attr( $args['child_categories'] ),
        ) );

        do_action( 'storefront_homepage_after_product_categories' );

        echo '</section>';
    }
  }
}
```

**Rendered HTML**

```
<ul class="products">
    <li class="product-category product">
        <a href="https://test.onyour6designs.com/product-category/gun-holsters/">
            <div class="pso-wrap">
                <img src="//test.onyour6designs.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/custom-gun-holsters-420x350.jpg" alt="Holsters" width="420" height="535" /></a>      
                <div class="pso-title">
                    <a href="https://test.onyour6designs.com/product-category/gun-holsters/"><h3>Holsters <mark class="count">(21)</mark>       </h3> </a>      
                </div>
            </div>
    </li>
    <li class="product-category product first">
        <a href="https://test.onyour6designs.com/product-category/magazine-holsters/">  
            <div class="pso-wrap">
                <img src="//test.onyour6designs.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/OnYour6Designs_Ruger_SR22_Holster-5-420x535.jpg" alt="Mag Holsters" width="420" height="535" />
        </a>        
        <div class="pso-title"> 
            <a href="https://test.onyour6designs.com/product-category/magazine-holsters/">
                <h3>Mag Holsters <mark class="count">(13)</mark>        </h3>
            </a>        
        </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="product-category product last">
        <a href="https://test.onyour6designs.com/product-category/on-your-6-gear/"> 
            <div class="pso-wrap">
                <img src="//test.onyour6designs.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Gear-420x535.png" alt="On Your 6 Gear" width="420" height="535" />
        </a>        
        <div class="pso-title"> 
            <a href="https://test.onyour6designs.com/product-category/on-your-6-gear/">
                <h3>On Your 6 Gear <mark class="count">(2)</mark>       </h3>

            </a>        
        </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

UPDATE: I disabled my child theme stylesheet, but the issue persists. I switched to the parent theme, and the category items display in a single row. I have only one stylesheet for the child theme.

UPDATE: Thoroughly checked the custom PHP function for syntax errors and found none.

UPDATE: I removed all custom functions and hooks from the child theme, but still have this problem. it seems like it might have to do with my template-homepage.php file, but I am not sure why. The only change I made to it was to substitute my hooks for the custom storefront template functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to include the relevant HTML as well when asking a question like this.  I'm including the HTML for the product category section you mentioned here:

```
<ul class="products">
    <li class="product-category product">
        <a href="https://test.onyour6designs.com/product-category/gun-holsters/">
            <div class="pso-wrap">
                <img src="//test.onyour6designs.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/custom-gun-holsters-420x350.jpg" alt="Holsters" width="420" height="535" /></a>      
                <div class="pso-title">
                    <a href="https://test.onyour6designs.com/product-category/gun-holsters/"><h3>Holsters <mark class="count">(21)</mark>       </h3> </a>      
                </div>
            </div>
    </li>
    <li class="product-category product first">
        <a href="https://test.onyour6designs.com/product-category/magazine-holsters/">  
            <div class="pso-wrap">
                <img src="//test.onyour6designs.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/OnYour6Designs_Ruger_SR22_Holster-5-420x535.jpg" alt="Mag Holsters" width="420" height="535" />
        </a>        
        <div class="pso-title"> 
            <a href="https://test.onyour6designs.com/product-category/magazine-holsters/">
                <h3>Mag Holsters <mark class="count">(13)</mark>        </h3>
            </a>        
        </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="product-category product last">
        <a href="https://test.onyour6designs.com/product-category/on-your-6-gear/"> 
            <div class="pso-wrap">
                <img src="//test.onyour6designs.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Gear-420x535.png" alt="On Your 6 Gear" width="420" height="535" />
        </a>        
        <div class="pso-title"> 
            <a href="https://test.onyour6designs.com/product-category/on-your-6-gear/">
                <h3>On Your 6 Gear <mark class="count">(2)</mark>       </h3>

            </a>        
        </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**There's several things going on here:**

If you inspect the output, you'll find that for some reason, the *second product* is getting the class of `first`.

Part of the styles for `first` are `clear: both !important;`, which forces it below the *first* product, which is `float: left`.

I personally dislike floats in this situation, so I would recommend adjusting the styles for `.product` to `float: none`, and keeping the `display: inline-block`.

Note that the styles that appeared to work for me when fiddling with it are:

```
.page-template-template-homepage-php .site-main .columns-3 ul.products li.product, 
.storefront-full-width-content .site-main .columns-3 ul.products li.product {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    width: 29%;
    margin-right: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Others may tell you that using flexbox is the answer, and I wouldn't disagree - it's just not my "go to" method.  (If you anticipate having more than 3 categories, and there's a risk that the category items may have different heights, then flexbox **is** the right way to go).

As a side-note, this style that you have at line 26 in your stylesheet:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Is a very "dangerous" rule.  I had a problem arise on a site that took hours to sort out which was caused by this exact rule.

I would caution you strongly against `*` rules.  The only one I ever use `*` for is to reset margin and padding to 0.

**Lastly** - note that your markup is incorrect within your product `li` elements.  The `a` tag opens, then a `div` tag opens, then the `a` tag closes *before* the `div` tag close.  **Assuming you are using HTML5** -the markup could be cleaned up *and* simplified like so:

```
    <li class="product-category product last">
        <a href="https://test.onyour6designs.com/product-category/on-your-6-gear/"> 
            <div class="pso-wrap">
                <img src="//test.onyour6designs.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Gear-420x535.png" alt="On Your 6 Gear" width="420" height="535" />
                <div class="pso-title"> 
                    <h3>On Your 6 Gear <mark class="count">(2)</mark></h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>        
    </li>
```

(if you are not using HTML5 then it is not legal / correct to wrap an `a` tag around a `div` tag)

Comment: HI, cale_b--Thanks for the input! I agree with the box-sizing rule; however, that is a woocommerce css style. I may try overriding it and see what happens. Thank you for including the rendered HTML--I was so focused on the problem, I forgot to add it:).

Comment: cale_b: I tried float:none and width:30%, but it didn't work earlier. I will try that again. May have been a syntax error:)

Comment: cale_b: It works! I just need to twek the other styles again. Thanks a bunch for your help! I racked my brains for hours trying to figure this out:)

Comment: You are very welcome.  Glad it helped / solved the problem!